# What are the most common vulnerability types in well designed code bases like Joomla or vBulletin?

Tags: security, sql-injection, exploit

I know that in poorly made codebases SQL injection and javascript injection were big issues. In properly designed codebase these should be fixable by only accepting form data through a sanitization bottleneck module and by explicitly enforcing this constraint on mods and plugins originating from the community, via code review.

Well, so once those issues are fixed, what are the remaining major threats / sources of known vulnerabilities? Are there similarly straightforward potential sanitization solutions for them?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno for the first, but I have certain answer for the second.

> could they be fixed by sanitization?

### NO

There is no such thing like "sanitization".
**Quite contrary - a belief in a such magic wand IS the source of all injections.**

There is no malicious data. There are *different data* in *different circumstances*.
And "general sanitization bottleneck" will never do any good, spoiling innocent data and leaving malicious one as is.

Whatever "sanitization" (or, better - formatting) should be done depends on the destianation of the data.

And just "daemon" (e.g. SQL, HTML) is not a whole destination point with single rule.
Say, for the HTML you need either `htmlspecialchars()` or `urlencode()` for the different destinations.
For the SQL it is FOUR different formatting techniques:

- for strings
- for numbers (can be combined with the previous one though)
- for the identifiers
- for the syntax keywords

each of them require completely different formatting, totally unknown at the point of your magic bottleneck.

Comment: it's possible to enforce the use of the right bottleneck method (get string from post, get int from post, etc) through code review and, at least theoretically, through various sorts of automated code analysis. But that still leaves us with the question, once we fixed all injection exploits, what's left? What are the actual typical known / recently fixed exploits in large php codebases?

Comment: quite contrary - that's IMpossible. you cannot know what you want to get from POST in your bottleneck.

Comment: Well you *could*, by tracking all the possible data paths, and that's what some automated code scanning tools *attempt* to do (with mixed results). But ultimately it's completely impractical to scale. Input validation is for enforcing business rules, output escaping is for ensuring all content is handled correctly (where security is a subset of correctness). Attempting to handle one task in the other layer is a recipe for disaster. +1